# In DQN, why y_i is calculated but not stored?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The DQN algorithm below

[image]

[Source](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/rl-dqn-deep-q-network-e207751f7ae4)

We have phi_t, a_t, r_t and phi_{t+1} fields in D's records. Why don't we have a 'y' field in D's records, so we can store 'y' values once calculated?

I mean, the minibatches are chosen randomly from D without any restrictions, so one record may be chosen multiple times, especially when the number of D's records are not large enough. If that happen, y needs to be recalculated multiple times. Am I thinking it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `y_i` is computed using the the function Q, which changes from iteration to iteration. Therefore, the values stored in one iteration are not valid for the next iterations.

Within the same iteration, I thikn you are rigth pointing out that if you sample the same transition several times, then it's not necessary to compute `y_i` several times, instead you can use the same result. I guess the pseudo code is more focused in the key concepts than in this kind of implementation details.